Cant access to macvlan from synology vpn
Im using docker in a synology. I've created a macvlan network where reside all containers, and a bridge network to connect the macvlan with the LAN with a static route.
When i am in LAN, i can access to containers, but when i access from the openvpn interface in synology, cant access to them.
Any help?? :)
Commands that i've used:
sudo docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=bond0 \
  --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 \
  --gateway 192.168.1.1 \
  --ip-range 192.168.1.192/26 \
  --aux-address 'host=192.168.1.193' \
  dockernet
  
  
sudo ip link add dockernet_br link bond0 type macvlan  mode bridge


sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.193/32 dev dockernet_br
sudo ip link set dockernet_br up

ip route add 192.168.1.192/27 dev dockernet_br


The default gateway your containers use is 192.168.1.1, which means unless they are configured with routes for the VPN subnet (with 192.168.1.193 as the gateway), replies for the VPN clients would be routed to your (home?) router.
In other words, you either need to configure the aforementioned route in the containers, or, make sure an appropriate SNAT or MASQUERADE iptables (or nftables) rule is configured on the host side for the corresponding traffics. For example:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

You may additionally / alternatively use -o match in the rule (with the name of the VPN's tun interface as the argument).
Also make sure the firewall (iptables and/or nftables) does not forbid the corresponding traffics from being IP-forwarded, and the IP forwarding is enabled (The net.ipv4.ip_forward sysctl).
Besides, I'm not sure which mode is the default one that docker will create the MACVLANs with. Very likely it would be the VEPA mode, and you may need to make it to create them with bridge mode for this to work.
